# Pass data from another master page asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I need to pass some data from one master page to another. Since my site uses two master pages. What I am trying to achieve is: Pass the location of html section from a link button of one master page to another master page.

Example code is as follows:

```
Protected Sub RedirectToSection(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RedirectToSection.Click
hashLocation = "DivToFocus"
End Sub
```

The Javascript code in is as follows :

```
     var loc = '<%=hashLocation%>';
     if (loc != '')
     {
        window.location.hash = loc;
     }
```

`hashLocation` comes from one master page and I need to pass it to another master page.

I think if I make the class public I can access the members of the master page. But I need a finely tuned 
way to do this.

Comment: How do you navigate from one master page to the other?

Comment: I am using an anchor tag to navigate from one master page to another.